# Setting maximum zoomin level in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I set maximum zoomin level in google maps, so that user cannot pinch zoom further in map??
I searched it for about half an hour but didn't find any suitable solution

Comment: duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700808/setting-max-zoom-level-in-google-maps-android-api-v2

Comment: maximum zoom level is 19f

Comment: check this answer on stackoverflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227378/android-gmaps-v2-bounds-and-max-zoom-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not restrict map zoomin feature directly, but we can try to get same feature like this.

add map.setOnCameraChangeListener

```
final float maxZoom = 10.0f;

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {

    if (position.zoom > maxZoom)
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(maxZoom));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(1), 2000, null);
```

Comment: this will not work with pinch zoom,it's only for first time when map is loaded

Comment: use then googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 15)); when you pinch