# How to get zoom level from CameraUpdate

Tags: android, google-maps

My requirement is `MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL = 14`.
Calculating zoom using bounds zoom more than MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL.

```
LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    if (i < maxNearestMarkers) {
       boundsBuilder.include(marker.getPosition());
}

CameraUpdate boundCameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width,height,padding);

map.animateCamera(boundCameraUpdate);
```

CameraUpdate class

```
public final class CameraUpdate {
    private final zzd zzaRp;

    CameraUpdate(zzd remoteObject) {
        this.zzaRp = (zzd)zzx.zzz(remoteObject);
    }

    public zzd zzzH() {
        return this.zzaRp;
    }
}
```

so how to get zoom level before animating camera to new CameraUpdate.

I required something like algo given below before `map.animateCamera(boundCameraUpdate);`

if cameraUpdate.zoom >  MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL 

then cameraUpdate.zoom = MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL

THANKSSS

**Note**: already doing so but it's zoom in and bounce back to MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
     mZoom = cameraPosition.zoom;
     Log.d("Zoom", String.valueOf(cameraPosition.zoom));
     if (cameraPosition.zoom > MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL) {
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL));
    }
}
```

Comment: map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL, 16));

Comment: In my experience the code that you added in your note is the best approach despite the bouncing effect. Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700808/setting-max-zoom-level-in-google-maps-android-api-v2 and https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4663

Comment: @antonio there should be way out